# Mix Blackwhite and Colored Photo

Tags: color, images, resolution

I have a set of images which I need to "merge" in After Effects (or any other programm which supports batch image processing): One image is a high-resolution black-white image, the other one is a super-low-resolution colored variant of the same image.

I was thinking there might be a simple way to merge these images so I can have the lightness/brightness resolution of the black-white one combined with the colors of the colored one.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi K Karl, Welcome to Graphic Design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop (and maybe also After Effects, I'm not familiar with that application) you can simply upscale the color image and layer the two images.

If you place the color image above the b&w image, choose the blend mode *Color* for the color image:

[image]

If you place the b&w image above the color image, choose the blend mode *Luminosity* for the b&w image:

[image]

The result will (of course) not be quite as good as if you had a high resolution color image to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Put the greyscale version in first, then the colour version on top and set its blending mode to Colour.  Both Photoshop and After Effects support this blending mode.

Depending on how the greyscale version was created (e.g how the original colour channels were weighted), it may also need a bit of a levels adjustment to bump up the brightness of certain channels.

Comment: Hi Mike D Sutton, Welcome to Graphic Design.